# Dependent task runs only when main task called directly

Tags: sbt

So, I have a SBT project, with two custom tasks `jooq:codegen` and `flyway:migrate` from [ https://github.com/sean8223/jooq-sbt-plugin, https://github.com/sean8223/flyway-sbt-plugin ]

Not that it is relevant here, but the `flyway:migrate` task creates the schema in the database, and `jooq:codegen` generates code from the schema. Hence, it is imperative that `flyway:migrate` runs before `jooq:codegen`. So, I added the following line in my `build.sbt`

```
(codegen in JOOQ) <<= (codegen in JOOQ) dependsOn (migrate in Flyway)
```

Also, `compile` needs the generated code from `jooq:codegen`, but the plugin takes care of it by default.

Here is the weird part. When I run `sbt compile`, I get:

```
~/N/p/d/davion git:data-access ❯❯❯ sbt compile
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/rohan/Nomadly/projects/davion-projects/davion/project
[info] Set current project to davion (in build file:/Users/rohan/Nomadly/projects/davion-projects/davion/)
[info] Done updating.
[info] Initialising properties  : /jooq-config4460313300896426081.xml
... OUTPUT TRUNCATED ...
[info] Table records generated  : Total: 669.172ms, +44.536ms
[info] Routines fetched         : 0 (0 included, 0 excluded)
[info] Packages fetched         : 0 (0 included, 0 excluded)
[info] GENERATION FINISHED!     : Total: 688.254ms, +19.082ms
[info] Compiling 7 Scala sources and 17 Java sources to /Users/rohan/Nomadly/projects/davion-projects/davion/target/classes...
[success] Total time: 24 s, completed 14 May, 2015 12:13:35 PM
```

So, the `flyway:migrate` task doesn't run. But when I run `sbt jooq:codegen`, this happens:

```
~/N/p/d/davion git:data-access ❯❯❯ sbt jooq:codegen
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/rohan/Nomadly/projects/davion-projects/davion/project
[info] Set current project to davion (in build file:/Users/rohan/Nomadly/projects/davion-projects/davion/)
[info] Flyway (Command-line Tool) v.2.0.3
[info]
[info] Current schema version: 6
[info] Schema is up to date. No migration necessary.
[info] Initialising properties  : /jooq-config6431105742854017589.xml
[info] License parameters
... OUTPUT TRUNCATED ...
```

I have no idea why this is happening. If a task chain is setup where 'A' depends on 'B' which depends on 'C', then shouldn't running 'A' execute both 'C' and 'B' (and in that order)? Why does 'C' not run as a transitive dependency and how can I remedy this?